# Can not get embeddeded document inside of dict with Eve

Tags: python, eve

I am building a read-only API on top on an existing MongoDB structure, and can not seem to get an embedded document to show in my main call.

**A sample document in question (redacted)..**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54a31721372a3b0f00000017"),
  "contentType": "document",
  "created": ISODate("2014-12-30T21:20:33.408Z"),
  "dcsId": "e14.0483",
. . .
  ,
   "metadata": {
     "amountTotal": 315.05,
     "amountNeto": 252.04,
     "partner": ObjectId("53bd4d851899424c0700005e")
  },
. . .
```

*partner is what I am trying to embed in a document call...*

**my schema for the document(used as ura)...**

```
docsSchema = {
    'dcsId': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True
    },
    'modified': {
        'type': 'datetime'
    },
    'created': {
        'type': 'datetime'
    },
    'downloadUrl': {
        'type': 'string'
    },
    'metadata': {
        'partner': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'partners',
                'field': '_id',
                'embeddable': True

            }
        },
        'documentType': {'type': 'string'},
        'amountTotal': {'type': 'float'},
        'amountNeto': {"type": "float"}

    }
}
```

**My schema for the partner**

```
partnersSchema = {
    "name": {"type": "string"}
}
```

**And resource definitions for both.....**

```
from schemas import coreSchemas

ura = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'documents',
        'filter': {'metadata.documentType': 'URA'},
        'default_sort': [('_id', 2)],
        'projection': {
            "metadata.amountNeto": 1,
            "metadata.amountTotal": 1,
            "metadata.partner": 1,
            "created": 1,
            "modified": 1,
            "dcsId": 1},
        'embedding': True
    },
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],
    'scheme': coreSchemas.docsSchema,
    'url': 'ura',
    "embedded_fields": {"metadata.partner"}
}

partners = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'partners',
        'filter': {'deleted': {'$ne': True}},
        # 'projection': {'metadata': 1, 'modified':1,'created':1, 'drive.webContentLink' : 1 , 'deleted': {'$ne':True}}
    },
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,
    'resource_methods': ['GET'],
    'scheme': coreSchemas.partnersSchema,
    'url': 'partners',
    "embedding": True
}
```

My call the the "ura" endpoint only gives me the id for partner (not embedding)...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding of subfields (of dicts) is not currently supported. From the **Limitations** paragraph in [Document Embedding](http://python-eve.org/features#embedded-resource-serialization):

> Currently we support embedding of documents by references located in any subdocuments (nested dicts and lists). For example, a query /invoices?/embedded={"user.friends":1} will return a document with user and all his friends embedded, **but only if user is a subdocument and friends is a list of reference** (it could be a list of dicts, nested dict, ect.). We do not support multiple layers embeddings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Would really like to see that ability in upcoming versions....